# AIR SocketServer with strings-why convert to bytes?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, serialization

Going thru an Adobe SocketServer code example of sending objects and strings from a client application to a server application.

In the sendStrings method I'm seeing

```
var bytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
            bytes.writeInt(TYPE_STRING); //message type
            bytes.writeObject(text);
            bytes.position=0;
```

But why convert to bytes if you're sending string data?
Can anyone explain the advantage of serializing string data?

Comment: because that's what is sent - bytes

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just the protocol requirement of Adobe SocketServer. AMF has't advantages vs String for single object as it's also uses UTF for strings:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class astest extends Sprite
{
    public function astest()
    {
        var str:String = "sdfKdkhsdfn345k4jhskdfhsdkf34k,,mancoasdc2";

        var bytesUTF:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytesUTF.writeUTF(str);

        var bytesAMF:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytesAMF.writeObject(str);

        var hexUTF:String = getHexBytesString(bytesUTF);
        var hexAMF:String = getHexBytesString(bytesAMF);
        trace("hexUTF:", hexUTF, bytesUTF.length, "bytes");
        trace("hexAMF:", hexAMF, bytesAMF.length, "bytes");

        trace(hexUTF.substr(4) == hexAMF.substr(4));

    }

    public static function getHexBytesString(array:ByteArray, colons:Boolean=false, position:int = 0):String {
        var s:String = "";
        var len:uint = array.length;
        for (var i:int=position;i<len;i++) {
            s+=("0"+array[i].toString(16)).substr(-2,2).toUpperCase();
            if (colons && i<array.length-1) s+= "-";
        }
        return s;
    }

}
}
```

output:

```
hexUTF: 002A7364664B646B687364666E3334356B346A68736B64666873646B6633346B2C2C6D616E636F6173646332 44 bytes
hexAMF: 06557364664B646B687364666E3334356B346A68736B64666873646B6633346B2C2C6D616E636F6173646332 44 bytes
true
```

But in general there can be advantage in size of resulting bytes of AMF (`writeObject`) vs String (`writeUTF`) if you going to write the same string twice as AMF uses the references for equals stings withing one object:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class astest extends Sprite
{
    public function astest()
    {
        var str:String = "sdfKdkhsdfn345k4jhskdfhsdkf34k,,mancoasdc2";

        var bytesUTF:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytesUTF.writeUTF(str);
        bytesUTF.writeUTF(str);

        var bytesAMF:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytesAMF.writeObject({str1:str, str2:str});

        var hexUTF:String = getHexBytesString(bytesUTF);
        var hexAMF:String = getHexBytesString(bytesAMF);
        trace("hexUTF:", hexUTF, bytesUTF.length, "bytes");
        trace("hexAMF:", hexAMF, bytesAMF.length, "bytes");

        trace(hexUTF.substr(4) == hexAMF.substr(4));

    }

    public static function getHexBytesString(array:ByteArray, colons:Boolean=false, position:int = 0):String {
        var s:String = "";
        var len:uint = array.length;
        for (var i:int=position;i<len;i++) {
            s+=("0"+array[i].toString(16)).substr(-2,2).toUpperCase();
            if (colons && i<array.length-1) s+= "-";
        }
        return s;
    }

}
}
```

output:

```
hexUTF: 002A7364664B646B687364666E3334356B346A68736B64666873646B6633346B2C2C6D616E636F6173646332002A7364664B646B687364666E3334356B346A68736B64666873646B6633346B2C2C6D616E636F6173646332 88 bytes
hexAMF: 0A0B01097374723206557364664B646B687364666E3334356B346A68736B64666873646B6633346B2C2C6D616E636F61736463320973747231060201 60 bytes
false
```